# Count the number of records in 1st column of a file using awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Is there a way to count the number of records in 1st column of a file using awk ??

My file :-

```
abc|87123
cdb|
fgytw|23321
ghft|
|87635
```

expected output:
4

I tried below command but its not working:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF==$1{c++}END {print c}' file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```bash
awk -F\| 'length($1){c++} END{print c}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/h3NtGd):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='abc|87123
cdb|
fgytw|23321
ghft|
|87635'
awk -F\| 'length($1){c++} END{print c}' <<< "$s"
# => 4
```

That is, the `c` is only incremented if Field 1 length is greater than zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F'|' '$1 != ""{c++} END{print c+0}' file
4
```

You need the `+0` at the end to get numeric `0` output instead of a blank line when no lines match the condition.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, this will check if 1st field is **NOT empty**(**not space**) and having length then count that field and keep doing this for whole Input_file then in `END` block of `awk` code print that total number of matches found.

```
awk -F'|' '$1!~/[[:space:]]/ && length($1){count++} END{print count}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Also change from `[[:space:]]` to `[[:blank:]]` in case you may have spaces OR Tabs also in first columns.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` + `wc` combination in this solution.

```
grep -oP '^\S+\|' Input_file | wc -l
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** As per suggestion in comments by RARE kpoop Manifesto one could try following also.

```
awk -F'^[[:space:]]*[|]' '{ count += NF == 1 } END { print count}' Input_file
```

Comment: you can make ur awk solution less verbose like this ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::: ::::::  awk -F'^[[:space:]]*[|]' '{ count += NF == 1 } END { … } :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: save time from not splitting out additional un-used fields

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
echo $(( $(cat test.txt | wc -l) - $(grep "^|" test.txt | wc -l) ))
```

To give you an idea what it means:

```
cat test.txt | wc -l
```

This counts the amount of lines in the entire file. Don't use `wc -l test.txt` because this also outputs the name of the file, which you don't need.

```
grep "^|" test.txt | wc -l
```

That's a neat trick: `^` means "starting of line". When it gets followed by a column separator, then it means that the first column is not filled in. So, `grep "^|" test.txt | wc -l` gives the amount of lines where the first column is not filled in.

Now, how to combine both? Well, simply using `$((4-1))`, which performs an integer calculation.

I admit, it looks nasty, but it does the job! :-)

Comment: `cat test.txt | wc -l` = `wc -l < test.txt` without the UUOC.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '/^[^|]/{++c} END {print c}' file

4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ wc -l < <(sed '/^|/d' file)
4
$ sed '/^|/d' file|sed -n '$='
4
$ grep -c "^[^|]" file
4
```

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple - 3 ways of saying the same hting:

```
{m,g}awk '{ _+=    NF } END { print NR-_+NR }' FS='^[|]'
{m,g}awk '{ _+=!__~NF } END { print   +_    }' FS='^[|]'
{m,g}awk '{ _+=/^\|/  } END { print NR-_    }' FS='^$'

4
```

If you don't mind to loading the file all at once, then even easier :

```
 - single subtraction + gsub()
 - no tracking needed
 - input rows become "fields" in this context
```

.

```
{m,g}awk '$!NF = NF - gsub("(^|\n)[|]|\n$","&")' FS='\n' RS='^$'

4
```

or if you wanna do it reversed order (admittedly, overkill for the task) :
.

```
{m,g}awk '$!NF= gsub("[^|]+","&", $!(NF = NF))'   RS='^$' \
           OFS='|' FS='[|]([^|\n]*[|])*[^|\n]*\n' OFS='|'

4
```